# Grammar question: プロジェクトスタート当初の目標のひとつであった

Tags: meaning

> 共催は、プロジェクトスタート当初の目標のひとつであった回復力のタクソノミーを、具体的な例に沿って検証する機会として大変有意義だったと考えている。

Having a problem understanding the above sentences and trying to break them down, would love any ideas on understanding better:

1. > プロジェクトスタート当初の目標のひとつであった

Is this meaning "(the taxonomy of resilience) was an original goal at the start of the project"? This is my best guess but it feels off.

2. > 具体的な例に沿って検証する機会として大変有意義だったと考えている。

I take this to mean "I think this is a meaningful opportunity to validate specific examples.", but I am not sure how this relates to the first part of the sentence, so I suspect my understanding is off.

Answer (score 1):

共催は、**タクソノミー**を具体的な例に沿って検証する機会として大変有意義だったと考えている。

プロジェクトスタート当初の目標のひとつであった回復力のタクソノミー

I think (this) joint sponsorship was a very significant(or meaningful) opportunity to verify/validate the taxonomy of resilience using concrete cases/examples.

Resilience was "one of the initial goals of the project".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what 回復力のタクソノミー is, but you seem to understand that part.

Read the sentence like `共催は、［〔｛（プロジェクトスタート当初の目標のひとつであった→）回復力のタクソノミー｝を、具体的な例に沿って検証する→〕機会として］大変有意義だったと考えている。`

- ｛（プロジェクトスタート当初の目標のひとつであった→）回復力のタクソノミー｝
  ｛the taxonomy of resilience, （←which was one of the goals at the start of the project）｝,
- ［〔｛（プロジェクトスタート当初の目標のひとつであった）回復力のタクソノミー｝を、具体的な例に沿って検証する→〕機会**として**］
  [**As** an opportunity 〔←to verify ｛the taxonomy of resilience, which was one of the goals at the start of the project,｝using concrete examples〕]
- 共催は、［｛（プロジェクトスタート当初の目標のひとつであった）回復力のタクソノミー｝を、具体的な例に沿って検証する機会として］大変有意義だったと考えている。
  I think this co-hosting was very fruitful ［as an opportunity 〔to verify the taxonomy ...〕］

Comment: Thanks...I think I often have a problem breaking big sentences down, I'll try to use this brackets technique in the future to keep all of the sentence components grouped in a more easily understandable way!